# Is it true that Morse function on non-trivial knot has at least 4 critical points?

Tags: algebraic-topology, knot-theory

I'm actually interested in the continuous case, for a non-trivial knot $S^1\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3 $ is it true that the function $\sin(t)$ can not extend to a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}^3 $?

Comment: I don't quite understand: For the title, a morse function on the knot is just a morse function on $\mathbb S^1$. It could have only two critical points. For the question in the body, are you looking for a function $f : \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$ so that $f|_{\text{knot}} = \sin t$?

Comment: @JohnMa yes, I mean Morse function w.r.t the embedding $S^1\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: You should clarify precisely what it means to be a morse function with respect to an embedding. I have an idea, but it would be helpful for you to be explicit. Regarding the question in the body, Tietze extension theorem.

Comment: @MikeMiller Yes this is the theorem I need, thanks a lot.